# Iterate a JSON object in Jade using gulp-data?

Tags: gulp, pug, pugjs

## Goal

Use Gulp to render a Jade template that iterates over the items in a JSON array.

## Problem

Try as I might, I can't work out a solution that lets me access fields in the JSON object. I've followed 4 separate tutorials word-for-word and I always wind up with `cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

## Code

#### items.json

```
{
    "wishlistItems": [
        {
            "name": "Boots",
            "price": 69.95,
            "notes": "Size 10"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### index.jade

```
doctype html
html
    body
        ul
            each item in wishlistItems
                li=item.name
```

#### gulpfile.js

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const jade = require('gulp-jade');
const data = require('gulp-data');

gulp.task('default', ['build-jade']);

gulp.task('build-jade', () => {
    gulp.src('./src/index.jade')
        .pipe(data(file => require('./src/items.json')))
        .pipe(jade({locals: {}}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to what the [`gulp-jade` documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jade#options) says when you provide the `locals` option all `data` on the vinyl file object [is ignored](https://github.com/jamen/gulp-pug/blob/v1.1.0/index.js#L34).

That means the following works:

```
gulp.task('build-jade', () => {
  gulp.src('./src/index.jade')
    .pipe(data(file => require('./src/items.json')))
    .pipe(jade())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

If you want to provide both static `locals` as well as per-file `data` see the third code example under **Use with gulp-data** in the [`gulp-jade` documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jade#options).